# I want to pass value to AngularJS method in controller from android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Hello I want to Pass value to method defined in controller in AngularJS from Webview Controller android. I am sending my code please check. Thanks in Advance.

```
myBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);
client = new WebChromeClient();
final MyWebClient myJavaScriptInterface = new MyWebClient(this);
myBrowser.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "AndroidFunction");
myBrowser.setWebChromeClient(client);
myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/angularjsandroid.html");

myBrowser.loadUrl("javascript:callFromActivity1(\'" + json+ "\')");
```

JS code

```
function personDetail($scope) {
    $scope.getPersonDetail = function() {
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify($scope.data);
        showAlert(jsonString);
    };

    $scope.updatePersonDetail = function(details){
        AndroidFunction.getJSONData($scope.id); 
    };

    $scope.callFromActivity1 = function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    };
});
```

Comment: json is a string which should recevied in msg in callFromActivity method.

Comment: Bump. I have the same need

Comment: well i have did it man

Comment: use the scope variable outside the controller and it worked.
let me know if you want more assistance.

Comment: Hallo @HardikChauhan can you explain how you did that? Or you can edit your question with your working code. I'm having the same problem. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, got it that way indeed :

```
var angular_scope = angular.element($("#main_content")).scope();
```

And then you do whatever you want with it

Comment: what is `#main_content` here ?